# String concatenation to show content

Tags: jquery, html, css, variables

i am trying to show some content by clicking on an element, getting it's index and storing it into a variable, then use that variable to show the content by concatenating it's id and said variable, problem is it is not working…

my jQuery for this part:

```
$( ".item" ).click(function() {
  // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
  var index = $( ".container .nav .item").index( this );
  console.log(index);
  $('#anim- ' + index).show();
});
```

And the rest of the code is available [Here](https://github.com/dangus21/personal)

I am aware there may be other issues with the code, but this is the problem i am focusing at the moment. Thanks very much in advance

edit: when i click the element .item to show the element #anim-0 / 4, nothing happens, i can successfully log the index but the divs #anim dont show on click

Comment: my bad, added an edit

Comment: There's a space after `#anim-`. Is that just a typo here, or in your actual code?

Comment: oh wow, it was that typo that was the problem, i feel silly… thank you!!!, if you want to post that as an answer i'll approve

Comment: I'll just vote to close as a typographical error.